# How to change this block's position?

Tags: drupal-7, commerce

Before this block was up there in position 1.
Once I shifted the position of some blocks, not replaced it with her on top again.

What is the name of this block and how can I reposition it to position 1?

[image]

Comment: The name of this block is 'Shopping Cart'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have any problem with your CSS styling on that block, position: absolute or something similar

Try clearing the cache (/admin/config/performance/clear-cache or drush cc all )

Revert back the changes to debug the issue:

May be you introduced something new , you are not aware of , or you can't think of .